# get POST request body and decode using mod_lua (apache http 2.4)

Tags: apache, lua, http-post, httpd.conf

I'd like to customize access to my website. I am reading mod_lua and I've learnt I can create a hook to handle the request. The request method is post, it has few headers and I have "Form Data".

My question is how can I get Form Data and it's properties.

Thanks,

Comment: Could properties from POST request be obtained exactly the same way as properties from GET request?

Comment: there are not same. for GET we can use pasrseargs() function and parsebody() is for post. unfortunately it returns nothing for my case

Comment: by the way in my chrome dev console I see the out put under "form data"